# Как убрать изначальные маркеры в GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps-api

Хочу убрать отображение значков из карты. Стилизация через GoogleMaps Wizard не подходит, так как карта нужна не статичная. В google maps api есть решение через стилизацию карт, которое и было реализовано, но оно не работает. Что можете посоветовать, возможно ошибки какие-то в коде или нужно по-другому переписать?

Значки вот эти - [image: значки]

Что есть в коде сейчас - [image: код]

Comment: Вставьте, пожалуйста, сам код в вопрос вместо скриншота кода (кнопка "Править")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что Вы хотите убрать называется business layer
Я убирал так

```
 var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
        {
            featureType: "poi.business",
            stylers: [
              {
                  visibility: "off"
              }
            ]
        }
    ], {
        name: 'Custom Style'
    });
    var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: location,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId]
        }
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);
```

element - собственно элемент на который происходит биндинг

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: Не забудь убрать кнопку на карте, которая позволяет переключать стиль, иначе пользователь сможет переключить.